# use macro enabled Excel file in OneDrive

Tags: vba, excel

I've created login_form that appears before worksheet and gets data (username or code) from login_form then filters inside Excel. Now I want to use this Excel file (.xlsm ) in OneDrive, that login_form will appear and users can use it on web (online). Is it possible?

And when users open this file in local, asks "enable macros" and "enable editing". Is there function that VBA automatically enables macros and editing in this file? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*Is it possible?*"
Not really clear what you exactly mean by "*use it on web (online)*".
But fact is you need Excel to open an Excel file and use macros. Therefore you cannot do this online, but the users need to (temporarily) download that file and open it locally then.

"*enable macros*" and "*enable editing*"
These messages are for security reason! So nobody can run evil code on your computer without permission.
There is no way that **you** can enable macros at your users site.  But you can sign your code digitally with a certificate which …

- … is generated by a trusted certificate authority (not free, need to pay).
- … is generated by yourself (free).
  But then your users need to trust that certificate once on their computer.

If the macros are digitally signed and the certificate is trusted you won't get the message to enable the macros.

Comment: Exactly!! (VBA) Macros cannot and should not be able to enable other macros. Yet, just to make your answer more complete you might want to add that you **can** generally trust all Excel files and open them with macros enabled. Of course, that should never be done and Microsoft also recommends not to do so. But maybe this is what the OP is looking for?

Comment: @Ralph I think he is not talking about himself having that issues but other users (3rd party users) to whom he shares his Excel file. So that would be only an option option for himself. Best practice here would be code signing.

Comment: Thanks your replies